# Regular expression whole sentence

Tags: nsregularexpression

I have problem with regular expression. Here is an example text:

"Status:   matched: 10:36:08 09/03/2013 from=0.0.0.0:162    oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.11536.3.6.1000  trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=60 days, 17:39:10.0 community=Cyber-Ark    agent=192.118.37.30 version= v2c    var1=italog var2=   var3=03/09/2013 10:35:37 ITATS426E Safe oniya_gemel is out of space.__"

Which regular expression should I use to match everything after “var3 + out of space”. I need the whole sentence as match:  “var3=03/09/2013 10:35:37 ITATS426E Safe oniya_gemel is out of space.__”

I have a regular expression toll and used

/(var3=)*(out of space)/

so far, but it matches only  “out of space”.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!!!!

Vesec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that there are characters between var3= and out of space.

```
/(var3=).*(out of space)/
```

The star states "Previous symbol repeated 0 or more times".  So your regexp looked for 0 or more repetitions of "var3=" immidiately followed by "out of space".  Ie. the star affected the "var3=" part, rather than indicating that there should be characters between that and "out of space".

"." in regexp matches any character, so my proposal states "var3=", followed by 0 or more characters, followed by "out of space".

Comment: How to do that please?

Comment: @Vesec Change your `/(var3=)*(out of space)/` to `/(var3=).*(out of space)/`